# Where to find icons used in Windows 10 Calculator?

Tags: windows, xaml, fonts, uwp, icons

Does anybody know where to find the icons used in the Win 10 Calculator app?  I know that some of them are in Segoe MDL2 Assets (such as the Calendar icon), but others I can't seem to find at all.  The icons I'm referring to are the ones in the NavigationMenu, such as those next to Scientific, Currency, Volume, etc.  I've included an image below of the Calculator menu for reference.

I know NavigationViewItem has an Icon property, and that property can hold any Icon type (FontIcon, SymbolIcon, etc), I just can't figure out what they used to display these icons.

**XAML Options:**

```
<!--Normal Icon-->
<NavigationViewItem Content="Standard" Icon="Calculator" />

<!--FontIcon-->
<NavigationViewItem Content="Volume">
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xED5E;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

**Image:**

[image: Snip of Calculator <code>NavigationMenuItems</code>]

Comment: I thought this would be a simple case of looking at the assets in the WindowsApps directory (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1812.10048.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets), but only the Date Calendar, Scientific, and Programmer assets are there. Will keep looking.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I didn't even think to look in the Calculator folder on my system.  I just figured it would be a self-contained application (i.e.:  single .exe file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the icons are in here: https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator/blob/master/src/Calculator/Assets/CalcMDL2.ttf

If you're running the October 2018 update or over, drag the font into an app like https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/character-map-uwp/9wzdncrdxf41?activetab=pivot:overviewtab to preview the characters and get the correct XAML needed to display it.

(Segoe MDL2 Assets font is actually just a subset of common MDL2 Assets, and many Microsoft apps have their own variants. With a bit of smart searching, you can also find the not-public "Full MDL2 Assets" font that has ALL the icons in it.)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I didn't realize Calculator was Open Source now.  This is awesome, finally being able to look at a (recent) internal Microsoft code source.

Answer (score 1):

MS calculator now is open source, you could get all source code and relevant resource from github: https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator

Comment: Thank you for the response, it's awesome to learn that this is open source now.  And there was nothing wrong with your answer, it was a toss-up as to which one to select as correct.  I only selected the other as it was longer and had the information about Segoe MDL2 being a subset of a larger MDL2 Assets, which I didn't know.